# Problem changing Web.Config in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a little issue here regarding the modification of Web.Config files in Feature Stamping (SP2010 [Web Application Level Feature, Activate on default])

I’m facing two strange Issues

1. The applied modification like (adding a child node) appears multiple times in web.config.
2. At feature deactivating, I’m removing the modification against the owner, it gets the modification, but 
   These are not removed.

I’m using the follow code snip during Feature Activation.

```
ModificationEntry[] enries =
{
    new ModificationEntry("someName", "someSection", SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode)
};

    SPWebApplication WebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
WebApp.WebConfigModifications.Clear();

foreach (ModificationEntry entry in enries)
{
   // CreateModification simply return me SPWebConfigModification
    SPWebConfigModification configModificationItem = CreateModification(entry, properties.Feature.DefinitionId.ToString());
    if (!WebApp.WebConfigModifications.Contains(configModificationItem))
    {
        WebApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(configModificationItem);
    }
}

WebApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
WebApp.Update();
```

This is what I’m doing at feature deactivation.

```
if (webApp != null)
{
    Collection<SPWebConfigModification> collection = webApp.WebConfigModifications;
    int iStartCount = collection.Count;

    // Remove any modifications that were originally created by the owner.
    for (int c = iStartCount - 1; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        SPWebConfigModification configMod = collection[c];
        if (configMod.Owner == properties.Feature.DefinitionId.ToString())
            collection.Remove(configMod);
    }

    // Apply changes only if any items were removed.
    if (iStartCount > collection.Count)
    {
        webApp.Update();
        webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
    }
}
```

Please Comment !

Comment: where is the code for ModificationEntry/CreateModification. You dont seem to have a 'path' variable anywhere (unless that is someSection), but then where is 'value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public sealed class EnableServiceAdapterFeatureReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
    {
        private string psSiteUrl = "";

    #region Not Implemented

    /// <summary>
    /// Install of feature - not implemented
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uninstall of feature - not implemented
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    public override void FeatureUninstalling(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Base Class Overrides

    /// <summary>
    /// Activation of feature - adds modifications into web.config and change masterpage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
        {
            psSiteUrl = site.Url;

            SPWebApplication webApplication = site.WebApplication;
            if (webApplication == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Modification(webApplication, site.RootWeb.Title.Trim(), true);

            webApplication.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            webApplication.Update();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deactivation of feature - removes modifications from web.config
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {

        using (SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
        {
            SPWebApplication webApplication = site.WebApplication;
            if (webApplication == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Modification(webApplication, site.RootWeb.Title.Trim(), false);

            webApplication.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            webApplication.Update();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies web.config file to add/remove SL Service Adapter support for the application 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="webApplication"></param>
    /// <param name="add"></param>
    private void Modification(SPWebApplication webApplication, string webTitle, bool add)
    {
        // system.serviceModel
        SPWebConfigModification svcModelConfigSection = new SPWebConfigModification();
        svcModelConfigSection.Name = "system.serviceModel";
        svcModelConfigSection.Path = "configuration";
        svcModelConfigSection.Value = "" +
                                    "<system.serviceModel>" +
                                    "<bindings>" +
                                    "<netTcpBinding>" +
                                    "<binding name=\"NetTcpBinding_IAdapterService\" closeTimeout=\"00:01:00\" openTimeout=\"00:01:00\" receiveTimeout=\"00:30:00\" sendTimeout=\"00:30:00\" transactionFlow=\"false\" transferMode=\"Buffered\" transactionProtocol=\"OleTransactions\" hostNameComparisonMode=\"StrongWildcard\" listenBacklog=\"10\" maxBufferPoolSize=\"524288\" maxBufferSize=\"65536\" maxConnections=\"10\" maxReceivedMessageSize=\"10240000\">" +
                                    "<readerQuotas maxDepth=\"32\" maxStringContentLength=\"8192\" maxArrayLength=\"16384\" maxBytesPerRead=\"4096\" maxNameTableCharCount=\"16384\" />" +
                                    "<reliableSession ordered=\"true\" inactivityTimeout=\"00:10:00\" enabled=\"false\" />" +
                                    "<security mode=\"Transport\">" +
                                    "<transport clientCredentialType=\"Windows\" protectionLevel=\"None\" />" +
                                    "</security>" +
                                    "</binding>" +
                                    "<binding name=\"tcp_Unsecured\">" +
                                    "<security mode=\"None\" />" +
                                    "</binding>" +
                                    "</netTcpBinding>" +
                                    "</bindings>" +
                                    "<client>" +
                                    "<endpoint address=\"net.tcp://slrsptm03.curie.sl.se/AdapterService/AdapterService\" binding=\"netTcpBinding\" bindingConfiguration=\"tcp_Unsecured\" contract=\"TDIWcfService.IAdapterService\" name=\"NetTcpBinding_IAdapterService\">" +
                                    "</endpoint>" +
                                    "<endpoint address=\"net.tcp://slrsptm04.curie.sl.se:8890/slHafas\" binding=\"netTcpBinding\" bindingConfiguration=\"tcp_Unsecured\" contract=\"TDIWcfService.IAdapterService\" name=\"HafasControllerService\" />" +
                                    "<!-- Endpoint adress for SL Client to MobileAdapter.ServiceController WCF service-->" +
                                    "<endpoint address=\"net.tcp://slrsptm04.curie.sl.se:8889/slMobile\" binding=\"netTcpBinding\" bindingConfiguration=\"tcp_Unsecured\" contract=\"TDIWcfService.IAdapterService\" name=\"MobileControllerService\" />" +
                                    "</client>" +
                                    "<diagnostics>" +
                                    "<!-- Enable Message Logging here. -->" +
                                    "<!-- log all messages received or sent at the transport or service model levels -->" +
                                    "<messageLogging logEntireMessage=\"true\" maxMessagesToLog=\"65000\" logMessagesAtServiceLevel=\"true\" logMalformedMessages=\"true\" logMessagesAtTransportLevel=\"true\" />" +
                                    "</diagnostics>" +
                                    "</system.serviceModel>";
        svcModelConfigSection.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;

        // appSettings
        SPWebConfigModification appSettingsConfigSection = new SPWebConfigModification();
        appSettingsConfigSection.Name = "appSettings";
        appSettingsConfigSection.Path = "configuration";
        appSettingsConfigSection.Value = "" +
                                    "<appSettings>" +
                                    "<add key=\"MainUrl\" value=\"" + psSiteUrl + "/Planeradtrafik/default.aspx\" />" +
                                    "<add key=\"TDIUrl\" value=\"" + psSiteUrl + "/TDI/default.aspx\" />" +
                                    "<add key=\"HAFASUrl\" value=\"" + psSiteUrl + "/HAFAS/default.aspx\" />" +
                                    "<add key=\"MOBILEUrl\" value=\"" + psSiteUrl + "/MOBILE/default.aspx\" />" +
                                    "<add key=\"SessionTimeOut\" value=\"10\" />" +
                                    "<add key=\"HitPageUrl\" value=\"" + psSiteUrl + "/hitpage.html\" />" +
                                    "<add key=\"SPGroup\" value=\"" + webTitle + " Members;" + webTitle + " Visitors\" />" +
                                    "</appSettings>";
        appSettingsConfigSection.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;

        // connectionStrings
        SPWebConfigModification connStringConfigSection = new SPWebConfigModification();
        connStringConfigSection.Name = "connectionStrings";
        connStringConfigSection.Path = "configuration";
        connStringConfigSection.Value = "" +
                                    "<connectionStrings>" +
                                    "<add name=\"SL_Portal_DBConnectionString\" connectionString=\"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SL_Portal_DB;Integrated Security=false;user id=sl_portal_db_user;password=[password]\" providerName=\"System.Data.SqlClient\" />" +
                                    "</connectionStrings>";
        connStringConfigSection.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;

        // httpModules
        SPWebConfigModification httpModuleConfigSection = new SPWebConfigModification();
        httpModuleConfigSection.Name = "add[@name='Session']";
        httpModuleConfigSection.Path = "configuration/system.web/httpModules";
        httpModuleConfigSection.Value =
            "<add name=\"Session\" type=\"System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule\"/>";
        httpModuleConfigSection.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;

        if (add)
        {
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Add(svcModelConfigSection);
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Add(appSettingsConfigSection);
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Add(connStringConfigSection);
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Add(httpModuleConfigSection);
        }
        else
        {
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Add(httpModuleConfigSection);
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Remove(connStringConfigSection);
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Remove(appSettingsConfigSection);
            webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Remove(svcModelConfigSection);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post the code for CreateModification() I have to guess about it, but I think something is wrong there.

It is important with the Name property of SPWebConfigModification that the value is correct XPath. Suppose this is what you're trying:

add [key='testadd']

This looks fine, but it isn't. Since 'key' is an attribute, like 'name' and others, this is the correct way:

add [@key='testadd']

This is causing multiple entries and makes the modification impossible to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This Class has all the required attributes, and it contains Value as well.

```
ModificationEntry("someName", "someSection", “Value”, SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode)
```

That’s not the issue, I’m able to add config entries into web.config file. Issues are as I described above.